# Promise appears when I try to create a detail page from data in a database

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes, fetch

I currently have the problem that i try to export data from my db.js and display them in my [id].js as single items. Should mean: within the [id].js the single item should be displayed via dynamic routing in next.js.

Because the data is local in my database I don't want to do this via fetch and just export the function from db.js to [id].js.

Db.js:

```
function getItemByDatabaseId(id) {
  return lostItems.find((lostItem) => lostItem.id === id);
}

export { lostItems, foundItems, getItemByDatabaseId };
```

[id].js:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getItemByDatabaseId } from "../../components/Db";

function ItemDetail() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const itemdetailsId = router.query.id;

  const detailItem = getItemByDatabaseId(itemdetailsId);
  console.log(itemdetailsId);
  console.log(detailItem);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Detail Page is working with dynamic IDs. This ID is: {itemdetailsId}.
      </h1>
      <p>{detailItem.id}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemDetail;
```

With a console.log of the detailItem I currently get the following error message in the dev tools: "Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope". In addition, the desired object is displayed to me as promise: "Promise { : "fulfilled", : undefined }".
As I understand it, no promise should be displayed here, since I do not fetch asynchronously and export the data locally between two files.
What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?
[image: Bildschirmfoto 2022-10-25 um 12 02 55]

Comment: I need to see the lostItems.find method, but I believe adding await before getItemByDatabaseId() should work

Comment: Looks like your database returns Promises for queries, so do the same as you do with fetch

Comment: Can you show us how is `lostItems` defined?